# Remove the tourists from photos

Tags: photo-editing

Sometimes I find an amazing location, but there are people in the way of my shot. If I want to take a picture of mine with the background landmark and people are in my shot which I don't want.

As I have more amazing pictures but gets a little less attention towards my style, poss or action in pictures, due to which I don't feel nice and become disappointment.

So, I want to know that, is their any new editing application or any different idea to remove the unwanted people from my pictures.

[image]

As in the pictures hear shown, I want to remove the girls who are standing or gossiping behind me. I do not want to blur that part instead I want to just remove the people behind me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step is to choose your location carefully — find somewhere where there aren’t many people gormless wandering around. If there’s a big attraction and everyone’s standing and taking photos, you’ll struggle to get a clear view without people in the way, so find a place where there’s a lot of movement. I chose the location in the photo above because it was a hiking trail so every person in the shot was walking.

Finally, take note of the actual landscape too. Waterfalls will end up blurry, and objects like flags will end up being removed. It’s also best if it isn’t a windy day so you don’t get trees moving and clouds drifting. These will end up as a blur in your final image.

Then head to Photoshop and go to File > Scripts > Statistics. Select "Median" for the stack mode and check "Attempt to Automatically Align Source Images." Finally, click the "Browse..." button to select your set of photos and hit OK. Photoshop will process the images to preserve the static background and remove everything that changes between the shots (the moving people). And finally you will get the required pictures.

Comment: You could do with being clearer about how this works, and the need for multiple identical-except-for-the-tourists photos. I.e a tripod and a little patience, or more patience to align the images. Flags above people's heads could easily be put back in. You may even be able to do something about the waterfall but people have a habit of standing directly in front of them.

Comment: Do you know of any android apps that let you do that without the need of photoshop on a desktop?

Answer (score 1):

In situations like these you could try using a tool like Content-aware fill, or resynthesizer.

Also, you can try to rectify the situation when shooting. Take a timelapse and combine the people-free portions of the photos into one.

Answer (score 1):

Not ideal, but even rather rough manual editing (not as rough as here) achieves much of what you want. If you care about the subject and not the background then you can take some liberties along the way as long as the end result is visually plausible.   eh here if it does not matter if there are or were chairs at left and nobody knows and/or cares then let there be no chairs.
Top right version has a long calendar which has regained shape again at bottom.
)Purple curtain (and a few other things) need work but almost nobody will notice in trip-record type shots.

I long ago "removed" 50 or so people from the stairs in a classic Macau church ruins shot. Close inspection shows the background to be a mess. Few notice.
The image turned up in 'slide show' so I'll post it here.

Photo: **St Paul's church, Macau.** Destroyed by a fire during a typhoon (!) in 1835.
The stairs had many many many tourists on them. These have been removed by quite rough editing. A look at [**the full resolution version - here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zq4ws.jpg) reveals how very rough this is. The end result is visually good enough for general purposes. A few people-pieces can be seen by the man's feet and further up the ring behind him. [FWIW - the image subject proper including the ring, bird and people are unedited. This "church in ring" view can be achieved with a little contortion but, to my surprise, about none of [**the internet photos of St Pauls**](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=macau+church&espv=2&biw=1422&bih=998&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi8xeaYp_DLAhUDW6YKHbSlAoIQsAQILQ&dpr=0.9#imgrc=bniXAVMKS7XgxM%3A) do this.
eg [Nope](http://www.shunya.net/Pictures/China/Macau/Macau-man-woman-church-frame.jpg) & [nope again](http://www.macaronmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Destination-Guide-Macau-St-Pauls-Cathedral1.png.)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should check out some tutorials on "compositing".  CreativeLive has some great classes if you can catch the right timing or if you're willing to buy a course.  The principal is to use a tripod and take the same photo several times.  One "plate" (that you'll use as a background), then one with your subject (you), and a few others that you can mask in or out using Photoshop.  It's fairly hard to write out in a few lines, but the idea is to have **exactly** the same framing with the people blocking different parts (or no parts) in each image.  You can then lay the images on top of each other and, using the masking tool in Photoshop, remove the people from the background.